# Component inside `transition-group` is rendered twice (duplicated)

Tags: vue.js

Here is a strange issue i am facing.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="fadeLeft" tag="ul">
    <section key="0">
      <testt></testt>
      <template v-pre id="myId">
        <div>My neighbors: <a v-for="(val,index) in myArray">{{val}}</a></div>
      </template>
    </section>
  </transition-group>

</div>

<script>

Vue.component('testt', {
  template: '#myId',
  props: {
    myArray: {
      type: Array,
      default: function() {
        return ['James', 'Mike'];
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
</script>
```

`transition-group` renders the component twice (and the second rendering is done without parsed "`{{variable}}`").
If you just remove `transition-group` parent at all, it works as expected and there is no duplicated content. So, definitely the problem seems somewhere there. How to fix that (so, retain `transition-group` and solve the problem)

---

*Please don't post answers "use component outside of app" or similar offtopic, i described the problem I need to find answer. Also, the aprior is that the `template` needs to be within `transition-group` decendants.*

Answer (score 1):

The problem:

In the `section` tack you have the `testt` tag which was rendered with the parsed HTML and also the `template` which was rendered as another literal tag (no rendering). And since `transition-group` elements must be `key`ed, the template had to be moved out.

The solution:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
 <transition-group name="fadeLeft"  tag="ul">
    <section  key="0">
         <testt></testt>
    </section>
 </transition-group>    
    <template v-pre id="myId">
      <div>My neighbors: <a v-for="(val,index) in myArray">{{val}} </a></div>
    </template>
</div>

<script>
Vue.component('testt', {
  template: '#myId',
  props: {
    myArray : { type:Array, default :function(){ return ['James','Mike'];} }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
</script>
```

Comment: Glad it was of some help. I updated the snipped eliminating the ul/li following yours.